# Date Range Not between a specific date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application where when a person enters come in the office he has to clock in and when he leaves the office he has to clock out. That is an attendance system.

Now I want to check using a SQL query that was absent on a particular date.

The table looks like:-

[image: Time SHeet table]

What should be the query to select a `personid` that was absent on a particular date?

Comment: Did you even try something? please try something come back when you have something, this is how this site works

Comment: You should be more specific to define "absence". A simple case could be that where there is no rows for that persona, for a specific day. But you can define absence as "being at work less than X hours", etc

Comment: Do any people work across midnight? If so what day are they considered "present" for.

Comment: also what if someone comes in and leaves two days later?

Comment: what is the condition which mark a person as absent? ex: one with null in and out-time, or one with in time but null out time or someone with no record in this table?

Comment: Martin Smith's question is crucial. If at one day, I come in at 12:00 and leave at 00:01 of the next date, does it count as having come in the office once or for both days (today and tomorrow)?

Comment: Maximum time a person can work for is 16 hours. He cannot work for more than that.

Comment: NUll InTime and Null OutTime is not considered as present days. Some with a Null InTime or Null OutTime would not be considered as present.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes it would count for 2 Days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PERSONID
FROM <PERSON INFORMATION TABLE>
WHERE PERSONID NOT IN(SELECT PERSONID FROM <TIMING INFORMATION TABLE> WHERE INTIMESTAMP=<PARTICULAR DATE>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to select every staff member from your staff table and then exclude anyone who logged in on a particular day. In short, this creates a list of PersonID not seen on a given day.

This solution works, complete with example cases:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (TimeSheetLogId INT IDENTITY(1,1), InTimeStamp DATETIME, OutTimeStamp DATETIME, PersonID INT);

-- last week
-- PersonID=1, didnt come to work last monday
-- INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-19 09:00:00.000','2013-11-19 17:00:00.000',1);
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-20 09:00:00.000','2013-11-20 17:00:00.000',1);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-21 09:00:00.000','2013-11-21 17:00:00.000',1);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-22 09:00:00.000','2013-11-22 17:00:00.000',1);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-23 09:00:00.000','2013-11-23 17:00:00.000',1);    
-- 9AM-5PM shift
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-19 09:00:00.000','2013-11-19 17:00:00.000',2);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-20 09:00:00.000','2013-11-20 17:00:00.000',2);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-21 09:00:00.000','2013-11-21 17:00:00.000',2);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-22 09:00:00.000','2013-11-22 17:00:00.000',2);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-23 09:00:00.000','2013-11-23 17:00:00.000',2);    
-- 11PM-7AM shift
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-18 23:00:00.000','2013-11-19 07:00:00.000',3);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-19 23:00:00.000','2013-11-20 07:00:00.000',3);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-20 23:00:00.000','2013-11-21 07:00:00.000',3);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-21 23:00:00.000','2013-11-22 07:00:00.000',3);    
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-22 23:00:00.000','2013-11-23 07:00:00.000',3);    

-- this week
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-25 09:00:00.000',NULL,1); 
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-25 09:00:00.000',NULL,2); 
INSERT #temp VALUES ('2013-11-24 23:00:00.000',NULL,3); 


DECLARE @ExamineDate DATE = '2013-11-19'

-- You want to select DISTINCT PersonID from your main STAFF table that contains all records, I did this for simplicity!
SELECT DISTINCT(PersonID)
FROM #temp A

EXCEPT

-- this query should remain as-is
SELECT PersonID
FROM #temp A
WHERE   
    CAST(A.InTimeStamp AS DATE) = @ExamineDate
    OR
    CAST(A.OutTimeStamp AS DATE) = @ExamineDate
;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```